# simple finance database, need some statistics, how to query?

Tags: sql, join

I want to use a simple private cashflow database. Nothing special.

Therefor I use a table "finance_flow", where I can put all my in- and outcomes.

```
Income -> amount > 0
outcome -> amount < 0
```

**Table structure**

table "finance_flow" with example-data

| id | category_id | amount | date | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int | int | float | timestamp | varchar |
| 1 | 1 | +60,00 | 5.2.23 | use for xy |
| 2 | 2 | -10,00 | 8.2.23 | to Tom for school |
| 3 | 3 | -8,96 | 8.2.23 | milk, bread, cheese |

table "category"

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tips |
| 2 | kids |
| 3 | shop |

Of course there is a correct foreign-key-constraint.

**What I want:**

I want some statistical data, for example:

-current status of my money
-total outcomes for each category
-procentual values of those would be nice

I know how to get the total current state:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM finance_flow
```

I know how to get the total per category

```
SELECT abs(sum(amount)) as total_per_cat, category.name 
FROM finance_flow 
LEFT JOIN category ON financeflow.cat_id = category.id 
GROUP BY category_id [WHERE date = 'february']
```

(Here I use the function abs(x), because I am not interessted in the sign.
The where-clause is optional, I want this, if the basics are correct, for monthly reports.

How to get the procentual values?

Can I get all this stuff with one query? :)

Expected result:

procentual_per_cat = total_per_cut / total_income(february) * 100

where

total_per_cut = abs(sum(amount)) for category x

total_income(february) = 60

resulting table:

| name | total_per_cat | procentual_per_cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kids | 10 | 16.67 % |
| shop | 8.96 | 14.93 % |

Comment: I was not the only one doing edits.....

Comment: Could you please add the expected result for the above data ...

Comment: Sure. I will add this.

Comment: I create a dbfiddle, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/aH5qEJuM   (not with the solution, but with the cirrent input data..... )

Comment: Thanks for that. This is what I already have. Now I want the procentual amounts.
I´ve made a edit in the main post. :)

Comment: Please take a look at how the other tables are formatted, and format the added data the same way.

Comment: Sorry for that. Now I know how to design a table. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the percentage is the same a dividing by the total amount:

```sql
SELECT 
  abs(sum(amount)) as total_per_cat, 
  abs(sum(amount))/(select sum(amount) from finance_flow where amount>0) *100 as percentage,
  category.name 
FROM finance_flow 
LEFT JOIN category ON finance_flow.cat_id = category.id 
WHERE amount<0
GROUP BY category.name
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/DHr3A0NK)

Comment: @EasyMathematics - Where you "don't care about the sign", it seems to be that you want `SUM(ABS(amount))` rather than `ABS(SUM(amount))`?  If, for example, a category has two entries `2` and `-3`, do you want the combined amount to be `ABS(SUM(2, -3)) == ABS(-1) == 1` or do you want it to be `SUM(ABS(2), ABS(-3)) == SUM(2, 3) == 5`?

Comment: Hello,
I want it to be ABS(SUM(x)) for following reason:

Let´s say I bring back my bottles and get some refunds: 2 EUR

Then in total my outcome for "shop" is

abs( sum( -8.96, +2 ) ) = abs( -6.96 ) = 6.96

The other way around would be sum( abs(-8.96), abs(2) ) = 10.96

which is not correct. :)

Comment: Later I want to play with a bar-chart or a pie-chart. And therefore I need the absout values. :)

Comment: @EasyMathematics:  When I edit my [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/hdj8CjeC) and add the example of bottles, I do get a wrong result.....  So, are you sure this answer is the right one?

Comment: The problem is the "where-clause" amount > 0, amount < 0.

I´ll think about that and fix it.

Comment: When I add the 2 as refund, the problem is, that this +2 is a "income".